# Karate: Can you use IF loop with particular steps to be executed if condition meets

Tags: api, karate

If the responseCode is 200 then assert the response and add the data to a variable,

Ex-
'''* if (responseStatus == 200) - **then do perform the below 3 steps**

- match body.header == "PASS"
- def header = body.header
- karate.abort()'''

**Can we bring the 3 steps in a flow if the if condition matches?**

**If responseStatus is not equal to 200 then do below**

'''* eval for(var i = 0;i < length; i++) if(override[i].type == "Demo") karate.appendTo (override[i].response = 'Good)'''

Comment: Can't we put multiple statement for a condition